# Integral comparison test.

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

Comparison test to show

$$\int_0^{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos{x}}}dx$$
is convergent.

Cannot think of a function bigger than this on $[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$ that converges. Any hints on what to try?

Comment: Near $x=\pi/2$ the graph of $\cos(x)$ looks like a straight line. What straight line?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to warm up with $\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac1{\sqrt{\sin x}}\,dx$?

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have an easy "bigger function" to use for a given function, such as $\frac1{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}$ in your example, you look at its "approximation". That is when Taylor's expansion is useful.

Since $\cos(\pi/2)=0$, in order to analyze the improper integral, you need to know the behavior of $1/\sqrt{\cos(x)}$ near $x=\pi/2$. (The point $x=\pi/2$ is also called a singularity of the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}$). The Taylor expansion of the cosine function is useful here. By truncation of the Taylor series, you would have a polynomial approximation of the cosine and thus gives you a way to find the "bigger" function.

But working with powers $(x-\pi/2)^k$ is not so convenient. So we can change the variable of the integrand. Observe that $\cos(x)=\sin(\pi/2-x)$. So you can rewrite the integral by a change of variable as
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(x)}}\;dx
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(\pi/2-x)}}\;dx 
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\;dx\;.
$$
Now near $x=0$, $\sin(x)\approx x$, and
$\displaystyle
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\;dx
$
is convergent. It is not satisfying that we use "near" and "$\approx$" here. But we can write this out rigorously in the language of limits.

In order to compare the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}$ with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ near zero, observe that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}=\lim_{x\to 0+}\sqrt{\frac{x}{\sin x}}=1
$$
which implies that for some neighborhood $(0,\delta)$ of zero,
$$
0<\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\le (1+\epsilon)\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}},\quad x\in(0,\delta)\;.
$$
Now you can conclude that
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\;dx = \int_0^\delta \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\;dx+\int_\delta^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}\;dx
$$
converges.

Answer (score 0):

From the limit comparison test you can see that the function $f(x)=\frac{2}{(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)^\frac{1}{2}}$ is equi convergent to your function. Since the limit is greater than 1 it means for $x$ close enough to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ the function $f(x)$ will be greater than your function. To be sure that it is greater everywhere on the interval you can add some constant that surpases the value of your function on the interval $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon)$ (Possible because of the cuntinuity of the function). On $[\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon,\frac{\pi}{2})$ $f(x)$ is greater because of the limit mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

> $u=\dfrac\pi2-x$ leads to: $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{\cos x}}= \int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{du}{\sqrt{\sin u}}$

> $\bigg(\forall x\in[0,\pi/2]\bigg)\quad\sin(x)\ge \dfrac2\pi x$

> $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}=2\sqrt t+cste$

> Or use directly : $\bigg(\forall x\in[0,\pi/2]\bigg)\quad\cos(x)\ge1- \dfrac2\pi x$