# Comparison for trigonometric integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functions, trigonometry

**Question**

I am looking for a comparison to test the convergence of the integral.

> $$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2} \frac{1}{\cos(x)^{0.5}} \mathrm dx$$

**Attempt**

I can see that this integral should be bounded above by the integral over the exact limits of $\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$, but I'm unsure of how this comparison helps me or if this is even the best choice to make in this case.

Comment: I saw this question a few hours ago and it seemed to have been answered. However, I couldn't find it. It was originally written as $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x}}\, {\rm d}x$.

Comment: @user1027216 This one, perhaps: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4442335/26091

Comment: @Théophile Yes, just that.

Answer (score 0):

$I:=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos x}}}\mathrm{d}x$,let $t=\tan \frac{x}{2}$,then $x=2\mathrm{arc}\tan t\Rightarrow \mathrm{d}x=\frac{2\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}$
$$I=\int_0^1{\sqrt{\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}}\cdot \frac{2}{1+t^2}}\mathrm{d}t=2\int_0^1{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^4}}}\mathrm{d}t$$
Let $t^4=p$,then $\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{4}p^{-\frac{3}{4}}$,So$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1{\frac{p^{-\frac{3}{4}}}{\sqrt{1-p}}}\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{2}B\left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4} \right) $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question was more focussed on finding a specific comparison, rather than computing the exact answer.